# got boolean datatype when apply(pd.to_numeric)

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to change datatype in dataframe as below.

```
df.iloc[:,2:8] = df.iloc[:,2:8].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notnull()
```

However, I got the dataframe with boolean not float datatype.
Can anyone tell me why?
Below is the before and after data
Before

```
     Reflectance U-Factor with Film [W/m2-K]  U-Factor no Film [W/m2-K]  \
0           0.08                       0.857                      0.984   
1           0.08                       0.857                      0.984   
2           0.08                       0.857                      0.984   
3           0.30                       0.273                      0.283   
4           0.30                       0.273                      0.283   
5           0.30                       0.273                      0.283   
6           0.30                       0.273                      0.283   
7           0.08                       0.857                      0.984   
8           0.08                       0.857                      0.984   
9           0.08                       0.857                      0.984
```

After

```
Reflectance  U-Factor with Film [W/m2-K]  U-Factor no Film [W/m2-K]  \
0           True                         True                       True   
1           True                         True                       True   
2           True                         True                       True   
3           True                         True                       True   
4           True                         True                       True   
5           True                         True                       True   
6           True                         True                       True   
7           True                         True                       True   
8           True                         True                       True   
9           True                         True                       True
```

Comment: If you use `notnull()`  at the end what would you expect it to return

Comment: well that's what `notnull` does, it returns a boolean array of whether the values are null or not. What did you expect?

Comment: @EdChum  - these guys are right... what were you expecting?
`df.iloc[:,2:8] = df.iloc[:,2:8].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()` Isn't this what you are looking for ?